# Why does a divs height, that only contains an input element, behave weird?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a div that wraps an input element. While trying to get the paddings etc. pixel perfect, I realised that the divs size behaves quite weird.

Why is the div bigger than the input?
This can be mitigated by putting `font-size: 12px` the `div` AND the `input` field.

But STILL the surrounding div is 15.3px while the input is 14px.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: lightgrey">
    <!-- add to div and to ipnut font-size: 12px-->
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: white">
      <input
        style="vertical-align: middle; border: none; background-color: green"
        placeholder="Hello"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An `input` is an inline element, so the extra space in the `div` is because of line height. Change the display of the `input` or set `line-height` to `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happening not because of div, but it's happening because input is an **inline-block** element by default. So just need to add `display: block;` in input' style.

```
<input style="vertical-align: middle; border: none; background-color: green;display:block;" placeholder="Hello" />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: lightgrey">
    <!-- add to div and to ipnut font-size: 12px-->
    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; background-color: white">
      <input
        style="vertical-align: middle; border: none; background-color: green;display:block;"
        placeholder="Hello"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```